# Firebase server time stamp same as local (almost)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is firebase generated server time stamp automatically converted into local time as I am getting the time stamp same as my local time or am I missing something?

```
_firestore.collection("9213903123").document().setData(
      {
        "title": title,
        "message": message,
        "deviceTimeStamp": DateTime.now(),
        "serverTimeStamp": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      },
    );
```

after running the above statement I can see both devicetimestamp, and serverTimeStamp are same.
But their is slight delay in their seocons.

```
Data In firestore...

deviceTimeStamp
8 August 2020 at 16:39:08 UTC+5:30
(timestamp)
message
"26"

serverTimeStamp
8 August 2020 at 16:39:16 UTC+5:30
title
"26"
```

The thing I am trying to do is basically ordering on the basis of date time and the user can see when he has created the notes, but if someone creates a note and stores it into firestore anywhere from the world(irrespective of location). Will, he/she gets their local time by using server timestamp(as I want this so can user see when they have added their document). ANd for safety, I want to use server time stamp so if a device is not in sync with the current time .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firestore's `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` creates and stores the timestamp in [UTC Epoch time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) **at the moment the request reaches the Firestore server.**

Calling `serverTimestamp()` doesn't create a timestamp at the time it is invoked and doesn't rely on your user's device time or timezone.   Instead, it creates what could be thought of as a *placeholder* for the date/time.  This placeholder is only converted to a timestamp once the request is *received* by the Firebase server.   As a result, the Firestore timestamp will always be at least slightly later than your client date/time (assuming the client time is perfectly synced.)

Using Firestore's timestamp should generally meet your goals of storing dates/times for users across the world in a consistent way, retrieving / sorting notes by creation time, and converting the timestamps into the user's local timezone client side.  You may, however, want to handle things slightly differently for scenarios when your users are offline.

See Doug Stevenson's [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-secrets-of-firestore-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-revealed-29dd7a38a82b) for a helpful, more detailed explanation of Firestore timestamps.